# Can someone please explain to me the reasoning for this question being closed for being "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion

The question in reference is here: [Where can I find a truly comprehensive list of all Chrome (Dev 10.20.5005.8) internals pages?](https://superuser.com/questions/1717661/where-can-i-find-a-truly-comprehensive-list-of-all-chrome-dev-10-20-5005-8-int)

I'm not too bothered by it being closed, but I'm genuinely confused as to why it is considered "opinion-based"?  For it's initial closure, I can understand the reasoning at that time: since Chrome constantly receives updates, the answer would quickly become obsolete as updates are rolled out and internals are changed.

However, the question was edited to reference a **specific version**; there will only ever be one "snapshot" of that version, and it's code (which *is* open-source, as the differences between the proprietary Chrome backend and Chromium do not, AFAIK, include internal pages) won't ever change.  Presumably, it stands to reason that **only *one*** finite set of internal pages exists, i.e., there is **only one** correct answer and it is not open to interpretation or debate, and it can be definitively enumerated as the source code is accessible to the public.

Comment: Why can't you get the list yourself from the source code?

Comment: If I possessed the required technical knowledge to do so, why would I be posting a question for it?  In my case, I'm not a developer, and have already (poorly) spent many hours trying to do just that.

Comment: Also, isn't that off-topic for this specific meta question?

Comment: @Arctiic - So your asking someone else to generate the list from the source code? The answer to your question would either require someone to share a link authored by Google and quote and cite it or look at the source code for Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

It's not strictly the opinion-based part to read into. It's the recommendation clause that is where the question falls out of scope for the site.

In a similar vein, asking for a list of all the books available from a specific publisher about heat sinks published inside a certain decade would be the same thing. To an extent it is finite, but it still is a list dump.

More to the question, a list of internal URLs as a list doesn't provide value. Understanding or knowing what URL to look for/use for a certain reason is better.

Comment: Well, in particular I am referring to pages such as `chrome://proximity-auth` which is not shown in `chrome://chrome-urls` for some reason, but very useful in troubleshooting device pairings.

Comment: Then we have to consider how would the answer appear or come about naturally? A list of URLs isn't as helpful as a pointed Q&A. Yes, it might be handy for a list, but in terms of Q&A format, it doesn't lend well to discovery or getting to an exact matter